# Load jQuery and plugins in YUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

I am trying to load jQuery as a YUI module, without adding it to the global scope.

The best I came up with, was to create a global `module.exports` so that jQuery thinks it is in a common js pattern, and does not create a global jQuery object...

```
// must create global object for jQuery to detect and attach to
// otherwise it will create itself in the global scope
module = {
    exports: {}
};

YUI({
    modules: {
        'my-jquery': {
            fullpath: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js',
            requires: [
                'node']
        }
    },
    onProgress: function (e) {
        switch (e.name) {
            case 'my-jquery':
                (function () {

                    var clone;

                    YUI.add('my-jquery', function (Y) {

                        if (!clone) {
                            clone = Y.clone(module.exports, true);
                            module.exports = {};
                        }

                        Y.namespace('my').jQuery = clone;

                    }, '1.10.1', {
                        requires: [
                            'node']
                    });

                })();
                break;
        }
    }

}).use('my-jquery', function (Y) {

    console.log('before');
    var jQuery = $ = Y.my.jQuery;
    console.log('walks');

    // regular old jQuery stuff here...
    $('#main').hide();

    // no global jQuery object
    console.log(1, window.jQuery);

    // there is a local jQuery object
    console.log(2, jQuery);

})
```

## DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/syvGZ/2/

Is there a better way to load jQuery within YUI without touching the global scope?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with using `onProgress`, but you don't need to jump through all the hoops of cloning and faking `module.exports`. The trick is to use `jQuery.noConflict()`.

`jQuery.noConflict` does two things:

- It returns the jQuery function
- It restores a previous version of jQuery if it was present, or it removes jQuery from the global object

Here's an illustration of how it works:

```
<script src="jquery.1.8.js"></script>
<script>
var jQuery18 = jQuery;
</script>
<script src="jquery.1.9.js"></script>
<script>
// the true parameter makes this work for both the $ and jQuery global variables, not just the $
var jQuery19 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
alert('is the global jQuery is jQuery19? ' + (jQuery === jQuery19)); // false
alert('is jQuery19 the same as jQuery18? ' + (jQuery19 === jQuery19)); // false
alert('is the global jQuery the same as jQuery18? ' + (jQuery === jQuery18)); // true
</script>
```

Another issue is that since YUI expects scripts with concatenated modules, `e.name` doesn't refer to the name of the module, but instead to the URL of the script that was just loaded. The names of the modules loaded in that script can be found in an array in `e.data`. This just means that you need to iterate over `e.data` to figure out if jQuery was loaded.

To sum it up, your script should look like this:

```
YUI({
  modules: {
    'jquery': {
      fullpath: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'
    }
  },
  onProgress: function (e) {
    for (var _module, i = 0, length = e.data.length; i < length; i++) {
      _module = e.data[i];
      if (_module.name === 'jquery') {
        // trap jQuery here while removing it from the global object
        (function ($) {
          YUI.add('jquery', function (Y) {
            Y.jQuery = $;
          });
        }(jQuery.noConflict(true)));
      }
    }
  }
}).use('jquery', function (Y) {
  var $ = Y.jQuery;
  $('foo').attr('bar', 'baz');
});
```

Plugins could be an issue if the scripts that contain them assume jQuery is in the global object (most do). So I suggest you host them yourself and wrap them in `YUI.add`.