# Load plugins for specific version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, yui

Assuming I have an old version of jQuery loaded on a page via a script tag in the head of the document, and then assuming I have loaded a second copy of jQuery, by spoofing a commonjs environment ([Load jQuery and plugins in YUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363701/load-jquery-and-plugins-in-yui))...

How can I load plugins for the YUI loaded jQuery without touching the global scope, or original jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the jQuery plugin in a YUI module. You can then wrap jQuery in another module and be sure that the plugin will apply to only that jQuery version.

```
YUI.add('jquery', function (Y) {
  Y.jQuery = jQuery.noconflict();
});

YUI.add('myplugin', function (Y) {
  var jQuery = Y.jQuery,
      $ = jQuery;

  $.fn.myplugin = function () {...};
}, '0.1', {
  requires: ['jquery']
});

YUI().use('myplugin', function (Y) {
  var $ = Y.jQuery;

  $(foo).myplugin();
});
```